# How should I declare a type for an Object being returned from a fetch call

Tags: typescript, fetch, es6-promise

I have a program here that is fetching information from the https://api.open5e.com/
I know the returned data will have the format

```
type ResponseFormat = {
"count": number,
"next": string | null,
"previous": string | null,
"results": Object[]
}
```

I have the following code here to fetch from the API

```
async getFromApi(){
    let response = await fetch(this.sourcePath);
    let json: Promise<ResponseFormat> = response.json();
        
    response = await fetch(`${this.sourcePath}/?limit=${json["count"]}`)
}
```

I am getting the error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"count"' can't be used to index type 'Promise'.\n  Property 'count' does not exist on type 'Promise'.",
> "source": "ts",
> "startLineNumber": 18,
> "startColumn": 61,
> "endLineNumber": 18,
> "endColumn": 74
> }

I am fairly new to Typescript and don't really understand how I am meant to declare types for promises
Have I declared this incorrectly or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.json()` returns a Promise of the response body, not the body itself.
You need to await for the result of `response.json()` to use it in further computations.

Check the example:

```ts
type ResponseFormat = {
"count": number,
"next": string | null,
"previous": string | null,
"results": Object[]
}

const sourcePath = 'https://api.open5e.com/spells';

async function getFromApi(): Promise<ResponseFormat> {
    const responsePage1 = await fetch(sourcePath);
    const jsonPage1: ResponseFormat = await responsePage1.json();
        
    const response = await fetch(`${sourcePath}/?limit=${jsonPage1.count}`)
    const json: ResponseFormat = await response.json();
    return json;
}

getFromApi().then(r => console.log(r.count))
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOYD2A7eEBiSBOBbAhsFALxQDeAUAEQDGSArisFQFxQr24BGE2ANNRQQAHszbxg2AJYoA5lAA%207egBsVAqmGwQAblIbxWUCdLmLlajdvirghtgHkuAKwg1gAbQC6FAL4UKOjQieAZsGggABUIACxIoAHIY4GAweBYAegz8MCkAOiRIFABWCDy6XAzECDV4BIBuAPx4EBQaKAAzRnd9FChZCGAMbCRcAEFcgAoASjZIkdwpdAAeOERUdCw8QgA%20cgooQ6ggiShrZDQo-AGARnj8AHd8KSIOwZoYydD6cKvgGOmjSOxw2RGcoRQ0VubDWF02OAIRFIj2eRHOGyutzy4NQMyBwKOByOJzRCDh0GRTxenXenwABgASMjfX7Rf6%20DIAfhUUkWwGITJxkOuEBu5QYTF8dOmRMOJKgQphZIxW0R9yppPWl2xELxsrOgx%20fSFjX8FAGQwWEykMzy-wgKEm2BIexOSBUZRUSFkTvFjGA02mQA)

Comment: Thank you that makes so much more sense now!